# Ionic & Firebase Facebook Auth in Chrome IOS

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, firebase, chrome-ios

**My Objective:** To create an ionic app with a firebase backend that can authenticate across all browsers, desktop and mobile. Currently, FB authentication works perfectly on Safari ios and Chrome Desktop. It does not work, however, on Chrome IOS, despite "using a combination of both authentication methods to cover all environments" as suggested by Firebase.

**Status:** Currently, I've read through countless StackOverflow threads, including and a Google Forum, but can't get a square answer on if its fully possible.

My code below allows for both OAuthPopup and OAuthRedirect, but Chrome IOS simply loads the same page and changes the url to include firebase_request_key at the end.

```
ref.authWithOAuthPopup("facebook", function(error, authData) {
    if (error) {
      if (error.code === "TRANSPORT_UNAVAILABLE") {

        ref.authWithOAuthRedirect("facebook", function(error) {
          console.log("this didn't work either");
          $state.go('app.home');
        });
      }
    } else if (authData) {
      // user authenticated with Firebase
      $state.go('app.home');
    }
 });
```

**Question:** Is it possible to authenticate via FB in Chrome IOS? If so, how?

I recognize there are many open threads with similar questions, but since the following fiddle demonstrating Auth from Firebase.com didn't work in Chrome IOS or Firechat, I started to wonder if it was possible:

http://jsfiddle.net/firebase/a221m6pb/embedded/result,js/
https://firechat.firebaseapp.com/